# How can I compute completions of rings?

Tags: commutative-algebra, formal-completions

I want to learn about how to compute the completions of local rings. For example, I want to be able to compute the completions of

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(y^2 - x)}\right)_{(x,y)} && \left(\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{(x^4 + y^4 - z)}\right)_{(x,y,z)}
\end{align*}

with respect to their maximal ideals. With the first example, I expect it to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ but I'm not sure how to show this using the inverse limit definition. When looking at multiplying the maximal ideal together, I found the following relations
\begin{align*}
(x,y)\cdot(x,y)&=(x^2,xy,y^2) = (x^2,xy,x) = (x) \\
(x)\cdot(x,y) &= (x^2, xy) \\
(x^2,xy)\cdot(x,y) &= (x^2, x^2y, x^2y, xy^2) = (x^2,x^2y, x^2y,x^2) = (x^2)
\end{align*}
giving a recurrence relation on the ideals, but I fail to see why the completion isn't $\mathbb{C}[y][[x]]$, which isn't what I'd expect since the first scheme is smooth.

Comment: Isn't it clear that the first one one just $\mathbb{C}[y]_{(y)}$ and hence the completion is just $\mathbb{C}[[y]]$? Similarly the second one is just the completion of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ and hence just $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$.